# Is it possible to reduce/eliminate MyPy errors for system level code with a command line option?

Tags: python, django, mypy

Running MyPy over my code, These errors seem impossible to disable with a command line option.  I don't want to mark the code to be ignored so that when they do get type hints things get better.  I just want to eliminate this from files in the site-packages folders, not in any of my code.

```
from django.db import connection
from django.conf import settings
from django.test import TestCase, TransactionTestCase
from django.utils import timezone
```

All of these suffer from this "error"

```
error: Skipping analyzing 'django.conf': found module but no type hints or library stubs
```

I should be clear that I don't want to ignore the non-existence of this code, just the non-existence of the type hints.

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but have you considered using [Django type stubs](https://github.com/TypedDjango/django-stubs) in this particular case?

Comment: I am using it now.  Does take care of a lot of the issues.  Thanks.  If this was an answer I'd accept it even though it only handles some of the issues, it does address the code example and I can't find any option to actually do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do:

```
mypy --disallow-untyped-calls --ignore-missing-imports file1.py file2.py
```

Comment: And if I'm importing my own files, this won't silently suppress those errors?

Comment: I'm not expert on  the subject, but if you list all the relevant files where I've written "file1.py file2.py", I believe they should not be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress all warnings from a 3rd party module by creating a [`mypy.ini` config file](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html) that suppresses import errors on a per-module basis, like so:

```
[mypy]
# The [mypy] section is for any global mypy configs you want to set.
# Per-module configs are listed below.

[mypy-django.db.*]
ignore_missing_imports = True

[mypy-django.conf.*]
ignore_missing_imports = True

[mypy-django.test.*]
ignore_missing_imports = True

[mypy-django.utils.*]
ignore_missing_imports = True
```

This is kind of like running `mypy --ignore-missing-module your_code`, except that we only ignore the listed django modules (and their submodules).

You could just have a single section for `[mypy-django.*]` instead of listing out all of the above, of course, but this may end up accidentally hiding any misuses of django that the django type hint stubs mentioned in the comments above may have otherwise been able to catch.

For more details on the options you have for handling these "did not find type hints" errors, see https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-type-hints-for-third-party-library.